Why does the media establishment still refer to the Syrian revolutionary forces as rebels?
The excuses given are

the situation is still very fluid
unsure if they will become an oppressive dictatorship.
continuity of use to avoid confusion

However

When Communism fell,  Lech Walesa and the Solidarity movement were immediately not refered to as 'rebels". Even though the situation was still fluid.
When the Ceausescu administration fell, the new Revolutionary forces were rather fluid and a stable government was not present for two years. But they were not called "rebel forces" as soon as Ceausescu was deposed.
When the Iranian rebellion against the Shah succeeded, they were immediately called the Iranian Revolutionary government. The situation then too was fluid. And no legitimate elections have taken place.
When the Khmer Rouge fell, the international community refused to accept the legitimacy of the Heng Samrim and his fractured Salvation Front in an extremely fluid situation, but they were immediately no longer called "rebel" forces.

So, why can't the news establishment stop calling the new governing authority "rebel forces", because technically the on-the-run former Syrian military and the Russian forces are the current "rebels". Also it is extremely unlikely that Assad would return to power to cause the revolutionary coalition of Syria to be rebels again.
Perhaps because no government has changed their terminology whilst the media is not neutral in some respects and prefer to defer to various governments' terminology preferences.
Perhaps the media does not want to be apparently seen as supporting a formerly, or still, jihadist authority but whilst they have had no issue terminologically "supporting" the Iranian jiadist rebel forces when the Shah was toppled.
What are the fine-tuning rules to decide whether a new Revolutionary authority is still the "rebel"?

To provide a specific example, the BBC currently refer to them as the "victorious Syria rebels" and "the HTS rebels who now control Syria".

I think, the "rebel" here is a placeholder for "revolutionary", because they haven't declare a "revolution" yet, but rather toppling of the regime.

When the governments mentioned in the OP fell there was only one clear  pre dominant  opposing group  led by  clearly know leader or leaders who were in charge. In Syria no such group exists. The only know  common denominator  of the who will rule Syria is that they are rebel groups. Hence the title and description,

All of your examples are, what, 35 years old at minimum? So expecting news sources to be consistent with decades-old practice is already shaky, assuming the assertion is indeed correct (since it isn't backed by citations from that period).

As for the rest...Lech Wałęsa won an election very shortly after the fall of Communism in Poland, so it's logical that people wouldn't really be calling him a rebel at that point, since he had become the establishment (nor do people really call the Taliban rebels anymore in Afghanistan, for instance). And in the case of Iran, the Iranian Revolutionary Government was what they called themselves, but did foreign news outlets tend to use it?

When Communism fell, Lech Walesa and the Solidarity movement were immediately not refered to as 'rebels" => source?

There's no comparison with Solidarity in Poland who didn't overthrow the government by arms. Even in Romania the situation was different because it was overthrown by protestors rather than a properly constituted army from a region outside the control of the government. Although as previous comments mention, you don't actually provide any evidence for your claims about what terms were used.

It would really help if you explained what name you wanted to be used, and why, so we could discuss that. I suspect there may be a reluctance to refer to the rebels as HTS or by a similar name because their relationship with ISIS and militant Sunni Islam isn't entirely clear. Indeed it's not clear what precise form of government they are planning to introduce or whether they plan to rule Syria themselves.

The question seems to be rooted on an expectation that there is a single universally agreed upon definition of what constitutes a rebellion, a revolution, or an established government. Given the subjective nature of these terms, I'm not sure there's much value in expecting it to be consistent between different cases of governmental overthrow.

"So, why can't the news establishment stop calling the new governing authority "rebel forces"" Consider the different between "can't" and "don't". There's nothing preventing the news from changing the label as far as you're asserting here. You're only observing that they're not doing so (and implying that they could do so with your question)

There are no clearly defined rules.
The western media has referred to the rebels as "rebels" for years. The new government's leadership hasn't been solidified yet.
It would be presumptuous for western media to determine who is the legitimate government of a country that has multiple factions. "Sometimes the factions work together, sometimes not" is a simplification.
When a single rebel force overthrows a government, it is much easier to say "the new government".

An additional complication here in switching terminology is that HTS is still a designated terrorist entity.  Were they the only party, like say with the Taliban, that might be overlooked more easily, but few are going to rush anointing them, unlike the OP's examples.  These are unusual circumstances overall.

The next few days will be interesting. The leader of HTS - “Syria must remain united,” he said. “There must be a social contract between the state and all religions to guarantee social justice”. If actions follow quickly and its not just words, then we should see a realignment and change of designations.

First and foremost, rebels are people in opposition to an established government/regime. Typically, these groups are comprised primarily of constituents of the established government/regime.
Assad's regime was the established regime, it cannot be a rebel of itself. Assad supporters can become rebels of a future government/regime once it is established.
The Russians aren't rebels in any case in Syria. They are foreign actors. They are part of a separate established government. They are supporters of a faction, much like Turkey or the US.
The fine-tuning you're looking for doesn't really exist. There isn't a central or main control for the media on a global or international scale. Each institution has access to different sources of information. One source of information is their own government. Other sources can be field journalists or informants that are in other governments or in the local area of interest.
A lack of independently sourced information on the situation slows down the media's ability to change or update information it shares. The more parties involved in a situation, the greater the burden on the media for collecting and piecing together information.
All governments, US, UK, Russian, free or not, influence their respective media to some extent. All of the major media establishments receive direction and guidance from their governments. Some of the agencies have more freedom than others in respect to following the guidance, but they all have some sort of direct/private communication.
This communication helps shape the general narratives.
The general conclusion that can be made from that is if the involved governments aren't sure of the outcome, the media will likely be slower to make more definitive statements about the outcome, especially if the media has trouble independently corroborating or verifying information.
So there's an information tug-of-war happening while the dust is settling from the action on the ground and the "rebel" groups are figuring out what they're going to do.
Its a complicated mess of international politics too:

Each major group involved in Syria has different sponsors/backers/supporters.
Each of the supporting countries labels one or more of the rebel groups as a terrorist group.
Each of the supporting countries has their own priorities and interests in the region.
These supporters have influence on both Syria and the international narrative about Syria.

Russia supports Assad. Russian media will work to support Assad and/or destabilize/de-legitimize any establishment of a government/regime in Syria not friendly to Russia.
This will contribute to continuing calling them "rebels".
Hay'at Tahrir al-Sham (HTS), the dominant "rebel" group in Syria, is supported by Turkey. Turkey will work to legitimize Abu Muhammad al-Jawlani, the leader of HTS, as the new leader of Syria.
The US has the most dominant international political and media influence of the involved sponsors, but they didn't win on the ground. The US supported overthrowing Assad, but don't support HTS. The US considers HTS a terrorist group. This puts the US at odds with legitimizing HTS or its members.
Also, while the US does sponsor some of the rebel groups in Syria, the US is a far stronger ally of Israel, which has its own goals for Syria.
Lastly, Schmerel puts it succinctly:

When the governments mentioned in the OP fell there was only one clear pre dominant opposing group led by clearly know leader or leaders who were in charge. In Syria no such group exists. The only know common denominator of the who will rule Syria is that they are rebel groups. Hence the title and description, –
Schmerel



So, why can't the news establishment stop calling the new governing authority "rebel forces", because technically the on-the-run former Syrian military and the Russian forces are the current "rebels". Also it is extremely unlikely that Assad would return to power to cause the revolutionary coalition of Syria to be rebels again.

(emphasis is mine)
This is actually not the case - Assad is still formally the head of the internationally recognized government and the rebels are not recognized as a legitimate government neither by any other states, nor by the UN. In fact, the rebels have not even decided yet what form of government they will establish... and they do not even form a homogeneous groups - some of them are propped by the US (notably Kurds), others by Turkey (who hates Kurds) and yet others by various states adjacent to or otherwise involved in Syria (Jordan, Iraq, Iran, and behind the scenes probably also Israel.)
There have been some hard bargaining and power play to influence the outcome, but nothing is decided yet. Depending on the outcome, various actors involved will call the new government a government or terrorist... thus rebels is a somewhat neutral term, allowing to pivot either way in future.
Remark
It is worth adding that some of the "rebel" factions are still on the western terrorists lists, with multi-million rewards offered for teh information leading to the capture of the rebel leader Mohammad Al-Julani.

Was Heng Samrim and Salvation Front not un contention wirh otgers to replace Khmer Rouge? Finetuning  rules and excuses?
